# Creating separate columns for single values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following database:

```
ID    onevalue  twovalue    S      S1     S2
ABC   0.568      0.004    0.568
ABC   5.620     -2.514          5.620 
ABC   -1.551    -0.452
LMN   14.56      7.456    14.56
LMN   6.750      2.896          6.750
LMN   5.620      1.166                   
LMN   8.640      3.486                  8.640
```

I want the higher values from 'onevalue' and 'twovalue' to be presented in new columns (S,S1,S2...). The program can go ahead and make as many columns as it has to in order to fix all values within the "ID" group but once a new ID starts it then has to restart from S0 and so on.

I have the following code for that:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame({'S':np.maximum(df.onevalue, df.twovalue),
              'idx': df.groupby('ID').cumcount()})
   .set_index('idx',append=True)['S']
   .unstack('idx').fillna('').add_prefix('S')
)
```

which gives:

```
    ID  onevalue  twovalue     S0    S1     S2    S3
0  ABC     0.568     0.004  0.568                   
1  ABC     5.620    -2.514         5.62             
2  ABC    -1.551    -0.452              -0.452      
3  LMN    14.560     7.456  14.56                   
4  LMN     6.750     2.896         6.75             
5  LMN     5.620     1.166                5.62      
6  LMN     8.640     3.486                      8.64
```

Is there a faster way to perform this?? My actual data has more than 90,000 rows and it's taking a lifetime to get it done.

EDIT for the answer given below:

Here's how the answer works with my data:

```
ID   max   cumcount   S0   S1   S2  S3  S4   S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10  S11
ABC           0
ABC           1
ABC           2
ABC  10.66    3                    10.66
ABC           4
ABC  11.42    5                             11.42
LMN           0
LMN  23.87    1           23.87
LMN           2
LMN           3
LMN  8.6      4                         8.6
.
.
.
```

Total cumcount for ABC is 250 so it makes 250 columns many of which are left blank which is not what i want. Here's my intended result:

```
    ID   max   cumcount   S0   S1   S2  S3 ...
    ABC           0
    ABC           1
    ABC           2
    ABC  10.66    3      10.66             
    ABC           4
    ABC  11.42    5           11.42                  
    LMN           0
    LMN  23.87    1      23.87     
    LMN           2
    LMN           3
    LMN  8.6      4            8.6              
    .
    .
    .
```

Is it possible to follow the S0, S1, S2... sequence per group regardless of its 'cumcount'.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this also does what you want to achieve. You have to test yourself if this is faster on your data:

```
# create sample dataframe
data = {
    'ID': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'LMN', 4: 'LMN', 5: 'LMN', 6: 'LMN'},
    'onevalue': {0: np.nan, 1: 5.62, 2: -1.551, 3: 14.56, 4: 6.75, 5: np.nan, 6: 8.64},
    'twovalue': {0: np.nan, 1: -2.514, 2: -0.452, 3: 7.456, 4: 2.896, 5: np.nan, 6: 3.486}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by='ID').reset_index(drop=True)

# determine max of the two columns
df['max'] = df[['onevalue', 'twovalue']].max(axis=1)

# max is a value
df['max_is_value'] = df['max'].notna()

# count row per group by using cumcount
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('ID')['max_is_value'].cumsum() - 1

# set the cumcount as columns and add 'S' as prefix for columns
# so you S0, S1, S2 etc.
df_pivot = df[['max', 'cumcount']].pivot(columns='cumcount').droplevel(0, axis=1).add_prefix('S').drop(columns='S-1')

# join both together to get the result
pd.concat([df, df_pivot], axis=1)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    ID  one    two     max    max_is_value  cumsum S0    S1     S2
0   ABC NaN    NaN     NaN    False         -1     NaN   NaN    NaN
1   ABC 5.620  -2.514  5.620  True          0      5.62  NaN    NaN
2   ABC -1.551 -0.452  -0.452 True          1      NaN   -0.452 NaN
3   LMN 14.560 7.456   14.560 True          0      14.56 NaN    NaN
4   LMN 6.750. 2.896   6.750  True          1      NaN   6.750  NaN
5   LMN NaN    NaN     NaN    False         1      NaN   NaN    NaN
6   LMN 8.640  3.486   8.640  True          2      NaN   NaN    8.64
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can u pls look into the edit? There's a little bug. Thanks

Comment: @Ramsey why are there no max values in some rows?

Comment: max comes from 'onevalue' and 'twovalue' and some of which are just blank so there are max values for them.

Comment: *no max values for them

Comment: Hey, i don't mean to be nagging but I hv researched online and can't find solution to a problem. Maybe u can help since u wrote the code:  i tried to add ".groupby('ID').ffill()" into df_pivot = df[['max', 'cumcount']].pivot(columns='cumcount').droplevel(0, axis=1).add_prefix('S').drop(columns='S-1') but it gives a "Key error"

Comment: I want to ffill values within S0, S1, S2...based on the group/ID

Comment: You have to add something like df.groupby('ID')[['S0', 'S1', 'S2']].transform('ffill') at the end. But otherwise just open a new question :)